# How to separate a Log4j configuration?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I've got a program that has a log4j configuration written in XML. I am trying to modify the original application, and attempting to improve upon the previous logger config.

Since I cannot modify the xml file itself, I want to be able to generate a new configuration through the `ConfigurationBuilderFactory`, and use it alongside the other config. The only issue is that, I am unable to accomplish this. It does not seem to want to work with both.

What can I do?

The following is my code, greatly simplified:

```java
/**
 * Internally uses {@link org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger}
 */
public final class MyLogger {
    private static final LoggerContext context;

    static {
        ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
        {
            builder.setStatusLevel(WARN);

            AppenderComponentBuilder console = builder.newAppender("SysOut", "Console");
            console.addAttribute(...);
            console.add(builder.newLayout(...).addAttribute(...));
            builder.add(console);

            // ... more configuration below
        }

        context = Configurator.initialize(builder.build()); // only works if no previous config exists, but will not replace an old config
    }
}

// later on...

context.getLogger("MyLogger"); // uses the xml config, not the one written above
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating loggers using the ConfigurationBuilder API programmatically you can refer below code.

It creates a logger in log4j2 environment added with some layout and appenders defined :

```
public class Log4j2Logger {

int counter = 0;

LoggerContext ctx;

Configuration config;

Logger logger;

String loggerName = "testLogger";

String appenderName = "myAppender";

static String testMessage = "This is a Test Message";

public void log() {

    final ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();
    final LoggerComponentBuilder loggerComp = builder.newLogger(loggerName, Level.ALL).addAttribute("additivity",
            false);
    builder.add(loggerComp);
    config = builder.build();
    ctx = Configurator.initialize(config);
    config = ctx.getConfiguration();
    ctx.start(config);
    ctx.updateLoggers(config);

    // To create/add the logger of the configuration specified above we can use the
    // getLogger(..) method
    logger = ctx.getLogger(loggerName);

    // Now we need to attach an appender to the logger so that our messages could be
    // logged
    logger.addAppender(addConsoleAppender(ctx.getConfiguration(), appenderName));
    while (counter < 10) {
        logger.error(testMessage + counter);
        counter++;
    }

}

private Appender addConsoleAppender(Configuration config, String appenderName) {
    Appender consoleAppender = ConsoleAppender.newBuilder().setConfiguration(config).setName(appenderName)
            .withImmediateFlush(true).build();
    consoleAppender.start();
    return consoleAppender;
    }

}
```

And for testing, you can have following in any test class:

```
Log4j2Logger testLogger = new Log4j2Logger();
testLogger.log();
```

This API helps you to handle logs in a powerful way.

You can :

- Create multiple loggers with your configuration
- Add multiple Appenders to it.
- Configure them also.
- Remove logger when the usage is over.
- Create Asynchronous Loggers also.

PS : I have used log4j2 version 2.12.1.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create your own *log4j.xml*. You have to ensure that your XML will be loaded in your program. So just define the resource containing your XML in the [Java Classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) before the resource containing the other XML.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, it is impractical to load a configuration before the user. I could, but it would become incredibly difficult to maintain.

Comment: Can you explain how you extend the program? At the moment I don't understand your problem with a new resource on the java classpath.

Comment: Alright, so I've got the application. It will load up its own configuration well before it begins to even begin to load mine. To be more specific, this is a minecraft modding scenario, where the resources for the main jar are loaded well before any mods. Since I have no direct influence on the resource loading, especially since my own mod will load much later on, I can't load a configuration before the main jar

Comment: How do you start the application? With a .bat file?

Comment: The application is started through a launcher, but for all intents, it's basically a wrapper for the java application.